# Are there file-naming conventions for .cron and .systemd extensions?

Tags: bash, scripts, files, cron, systemd

I'm starting to rename all my existing bash scripts in `/home/Me/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` from no extension to a `.sh` extension. The reason is the exact same file name with drastically different contents and purposes will sometimes exist in `/etc/cron.d` or `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`. This is causing false-positives with `locate --regex '<file_name>'` searches.

I've googled around and can't find any file extension naming conventions for `cron` or `systemd`.

- If I went with DOS 8.3 conventions I would pick `.crn` and `.syd`
- If I went with 4 characters it I would pick `.cron` and `.sysd`
- If I went with 2 characters like `.sh` I would pick `.cr` and `.sd`

I've seen `.py` used for Python, `.c` for C program, `.h` for header file, `.o` for compiled object. This leads me to presume the Linux-verse would prefer two character extensions. I think the four character extensions are more readable. I don't see any need for DOS 8.3 format since the old 8.x component is now 256.x in size or something like that. Systemd service files buck the "shorter-is-better" trend with `.service` files instead of `.sr` or `.srv`.

Before I go through the labour of renaming files and editing the parents that call the files with new names, **are there any existing file extension conventions**?

Note that if you or your organization has internal standards, that would be a perfectly acceptable answer, in absence of industry standards.

---

Just found a [launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cron/+bug/706565) where a user named a job `/etc/cron.d/job.cron` and it crashed due to the `.` in the name. The bug was filed in 2011 and confirmed, but still not fixed.

This means all my extensions will have to start with `-` instead of `.`

Comment: There for sure are for `/etc/cron.d` - see the `DEBIAN SPECIFIC` section of `man 8 cron`

Comment: @steeldriver Interesting I use Debian/Ubuntu at home and REHL at work. A few minutes ago I read these are the only two distros that use `/etc/cron.d` to complement `crontab -e`. I just read the man 8 and it mentions nothing about extensions? All my existing `/etc/cron.d` scripts have no extension and work fine.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/cron.8.html: "Files  in  this  directory  ... must  conform  to  the  same naming convention as used by run-parts(8): they must consist solely of  upper-  and  lower-case  letters,  digits, underscores, and hyphens. This means that they **cannot** contain any dots." i.e., no extensions.

Comment: @muru There is discussion about that in the confirmed bug report I added to my question a few minutes ago before I read your comment just now.